# "indicate confirmation" or "indicate a confirmation"

Tags: word-usage

A friend and I were talking about intonation, I said

> I guess people could use rising tone to **indicate confirmation**.

Should I have said it this way?

> ... to **indicate a confirmation**.

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/confirmation), "confirmation" could be either countable or uncountable.
Which one should I go with in this particular situation?

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indicate%20confirmation%2C%20indicate%20a%20confirmation&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindicate%20confirmation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindicate%20a%20confirmation%3B%2Cc0) shows the former is more common while the latter is not quite rare.

[image]

Comment: Rising intonation indicates a question—which means uncertainty, not confirmation. Confirmation, if it's possible only from tone of voice, would be indicated by speaking louder and in a neutral if not *lowered* tone.

Comment: (There should be no article in this case. But it could be ***their*** *confirmation* in this sentence.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you. "indicate confirmation" and "indicate their  confirmation", which one is more clear and natural?

Comment: Probably just *indicate confirmation*.